# wxChoice::SetString() Index Error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I've finally gotten around to messing with the wxChoice control in my application, and for some reason whenever I attempt to modify the text of a column, I get the error:

> ....\src\msw\choice.cpp(348): assert "IsValid(n)" failed in
>   wxChoice::SetString(): invalid item index in wxChoice::SetString

The error itself makes it quite obvious that the item index isn't valid, but based off of my code and the (not very descriptive) [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.2/classwx_choice.html), I should only need to set the number of columns, then I'd be allowed to edit the text at a given index.

Here's a snippet from my project:

```
int phones = Phones->size();
choiceDevice->SetColumns(phones); // Value greater than 0
choiceDevice->SetString(phones - 1, pInstance->ProfileName); // Should assign the last index the value of the ProfileName.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex had said, I shouldn't be using wxChoice::SetColumns on Windows since it has no affect.  I found that I have to use wxChoice::Append instead of setting the number of columns, then setting the individual string.

Answer (score 0):

What if `Phones` is empty, and thus `phones == 0`?

Comment: I've checked that, and I've tried setting `choiceDevice->SetColumns(phones);` to `choiceDevice->SetColumns(1);` with index 0 at SetString and still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

wxChoice::SetColumns

Remarks:

**This is implemented for GTK and Motif only and doesn’t do anything under other platforms.**

It looks like SetColumns is used for multi-column choice control, I have never seen it. Anyway, it doesn't add new items to the control. In Windows it does nothing in any case.

Comment: Thank you so, so much for noticing that.  While that doesn't exactly help my problem, I'll take it as an answer since I'm doing something else wrong, and *that* wasn't the issue.  Time to hunt down some similar methods or samples that utilize the control on Windows.